Question Regarding the proof to $\text{dim}(K_n)\geq \log_2{\log_2{n}}$ as in Proofs from the Book
The dimension of a complete graph is defined as the size of the smallest representation of $K_n$ in Proofs from the Book. More specifically, it is the minimum permutation set $\{\pi_i\}$ on the first $n$ positive integers $[n]$ satisfying the property that for any three distinct $i,j,k \in[n]$, there exists a permutation $\pi_k$ such that $k$ comes after both $i$ and $j$. The Book presents a proof to the inequality

$\begin{equation}
\text{dim}(K_n)\geq \log_2{\log_2{n}}.
\end{equation}$

However, I am confused by this claim: since $\text{dim}(K_n)$ is monotonically increasing, it suffices to prove that the inequality holds for $n=2^{2^p}+1$.
I don't see how the proof for general $n$ follows from the proof for $n=2^{2^p}+1$. Indeed, if we could prove for $n=2^{2^p}$ then since the right hand side only takes on integer values when $n$ is of this form then we could conclude the inequality is true for all $n$.
Yet if $n=2^{2^p}+1$ then it might be that $\text{dim}(K_{n-1})-\text{dim}(K_{n-1})\geq 2$, potentially causing LHS to drop below RHS. How do I show that this will never happen, or did I misunderstand something?

The only things needed are that $\text{dim}(K_n)$ and that the inequality is satisfied for $n = 2^{2^p} + 1$.
First, having the inequality for $n = 2^{2^p} + 1$ is equivalent to $\text{dim}(K_n) \geq p + 1$. This is due to the fact that $\text{dim}(K_n)$ takes integer values. We have $\text{dim}(K_n) \geq \log_2(\log_2(2^{2^p} + 1)) \gt \log_2(\log_2(2^{2^p})) = p$, so since $\text{dim}(K_n)$ is strictly greater than $p$, it must be at least $p + 1$. The other direction of the equivalence between these facts is trivial since $p + 1 \geq p$.
Then the general result follows: if $n = 2^{2^p} + 1 \leq m \leq 2^{2^{p + 1}}$, then
$$
\text{dim}(K_m) \geq \text{dim}(K_n) \geq p + 1 = \log_2(\log_2(2^{2^{p + 1}})) \geq \log_2(\log_2(m))
$$
Of course, this excludes the cases with $m < 3$ since no value of $p$ makes $2^{2^p} + 1 \leq 2$ true, but for $m = 2$ the inequality is trivial and for $m = 0$ and $m = 1$, $\log_2(\log_2(m))$ is undefined, so those values of $m$ are implicitly not included.

The reason the same argument fails if we prove the inequality true for $n = 2^{2^p}$ instead is that now we don't get $\text{dim}(K_n) \geq p + 1$. That means that we can't say that $\text{dim}(K_n) \geq \log_2(\log_2(m))$ for $m \leq 2^{2^{p + 1}}$ and the whole proof falls apart. We need the extra space from that $+1$ to get the correct lower bound.
